# IIS 7.5 Files Edited Using FTP Lose Permissions

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, file-permissions, user-permissions, web-applications

I have a web application running IIS 7.5, I have a few files that require that the I_USER have write/modify permissions. When these permissions have been applied and the application runs smoothly. However the application also allows FTP access to the folder. Whenever the files with write/modify permissions for IUSER are modified using an FTP Account, the permissions are lost and I have to manually remote into the server and apply the write modify permissions or the web application will throw an error when it tries to modify the files. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

My guess is that when a file is modified using FTP it is literally deleting the file and creating it again, which in that case the file would default back to its root folder's permissions. How do I prevent this without giving the entire folder write/modify permissions for the I_USER?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to modify the behaviour of the FTP client doing the work, if at all possible. That sounds like what you need the solution to be.

Alternatively can you get the FTP server's home dir to be in a different location, and for the web server to copy the files over as per a cron/scheduled task so that it has the correct permissions? Or do it as part of a script that is executed upon FTP client disconnect?

Comment: The FTP Application we are using on the server is CrushFTP, is there anything we can change with how that works, or do we need to use a different FTP Program?